# How is the matrix square root defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am wondering how the square root of a positive definite matrix is formally defined.

The square root of a positive definite matrix $A$ is $A^{1/2}$ if $A^{1/2}A^{1/2}= A$. However, I have also seen definitions that has $A^{1/2}$ as the square root of a matrix A if ${A^{1/2}}^T A^{1/2} = A$, which is confusing to me.

Furthermore, if I define the square root of a positive definite matrix $A$ to be $A^{1/2}$, and the square root of $A^{-1}$ is $A^{-1/2}$, is it necessarily true that $A^{1/2}A^{-1/2} = I$? Or would it be ${A^{1/2}}^TA^{-1/2} = I$? thanks.

Comment: Is $A$ positive, i.e. it has non-negative eigenvalues? Otherwise, you do not have a unique way of choosing a square root for $A$.

Comment: Yes, sorry to not have mentioned. I am taking $A$ to be a positive definite matrix, like a covariance matrix.

Comment: If $A$ is a symmetric positive (semi)definite matrix, then $A^{1/2}$ is chosen to also be symmetric and positive (semi)definite. Therefore there is no difference between $A^{1/2}A^{1/2}$ and $(A^{1/2})^TA^{1/2}$.

Comment: What have you understood from $A^{\frac{1}{2}}A^{\frac{1}{2}}=A$, $A^{-\frac{1}{2}}A^{-\frac{1}{2}}=A^{-1}$, and $AA^{-1}=I$ that suggests or requires $A^{\frac{1}{2}}A^{-\frac{1}{2}}= I$?

Comment: Also if $A^{\frac{1}{2}}A^{\frac{1}{2}}=A$ then denote inverse of $A^{\frac{1}{2}}$ by $A^{\frac{1}{2}}_{-1}$. Then it is clear that $A^{\frac{1}{2}}A^{\frac{1}{2}}_{-1}=I$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $A$ is positive definite, then we have that
\begin{align}
A = Q^TDQ
\end{align}
where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with non-negative entries. Then define
\begin{align}
A^{1/2} = Q^TD^{1/2}Q
\end{align}
i.e. we look at the square root of each entries in the diagonal matrix.

Then observe
\begin{align}
A^{1/2}A^{1/2} = Q^TD^{1/2}QQ^TD^{1/2}Q = Q^TD^{1/2}D^{1/2}Q = Q^TD Q= A. 
\end{align}

Answer (score 5):

The Cholesky factorization $A=R^{T}R$ where $R$ is upper triangular with positive entries on the diagonal can often be used as an effective "square root" of a symmetric and positive definite matrix $A$.  It's relatively fast to compute.

If $A$ is symmetric and positive definite, it will also have a symmetric and positive definite matrix square root $S$, with $A=S^{2}$.  This can be computed from the eigenvalue decomposition of $A$ as explained in Jacky Chong's answer, or by some special purpose algorithms.  The symmetric matrix square root is quite a bit slower to compute than the Cholesky factorization.

It is unfortunate that some authors choose to refer to the Cholesky factorization as a "square root", but this is fairly common.  It would be better if these authors used the term Cholesky factorization instead.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "effective square root", can you clarify?

Comment: Depending on what you need the matrix square root for, the Cholesky factorization might do the job.  For example, you can convert $\min (Ax-b)^{T}W(Ax-b)$ into a linear least squares problem using $W=R^{T}R$ and minimizing $\| (RA)x-Rb \|$.